# How to properly recreate SecretKey from string

Tags: java, encryption, secret-key

I'm trying to make an encryption-decryption app. I've got two classes - one with functions to generate the key, encrypt and decrypt, second one for JavaFX GUI. In the GUI class I've got 4 textareas: 1st to write text to encrypt, 2nd for encrypted text, 3rd for the key (`String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(klucz.getEncoded());`) and 4th for decrypted text.

The problem is, I am not able to decrypt the text. I'm trying to recreate the SecretKey like this:

```
String encodedKey = textAreaKey.getText();                
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
SecretKey klucz = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "DESede");
```

When I encrypt the key looks like this: `com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeKey@4f964d80` and when I try to recreate it: `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@4f964d80` and I'm getting `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Here is my 1st class:

```
public class Encryption {

    public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Security.addProvider(new com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE());
        KeyGenerator keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DESede");
        keygen.init(168);
        SecretKey klucz = keygen.generateKey();

        return klucz;
    }

    static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainTextByte, SecretKey klucz)
        throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, klucz);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plainTextByte);
        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedBytes, SecretKey klucz)
        throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, klucz);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);
        return decryptedBytes;
    }
}
```

edit

```
    btnEncrypt.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        try {
            String plainText = textAreaToEncrypt.getText();
            SecretKey klucz = Encryption.generateKey();                
            byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes();                
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Encryption.encrypt(plainTextByte, klucz);                
            String encryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
            textAreaEncryptedText.setText(encryptedText);                
            byte[] byteKey = klucz.getEncoded();
            String stringKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteKey);
            textAreaKey.setTextstringKey
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    btnDecrypt.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        try {
            String stringKey = textAreaKey.getText();                
            byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
            SecretKey klucz2 = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "DESede");                
            String encryptedText = textAreaEncryptedText.getText();
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText.getBytes());                
            byte[] decryptedBytes = Encryption.decrypt(encryptedBytes, klucz2;
            String decryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(decryptedBytes);

            textAreaDecryptedText.setText(decryptedText);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: I used the code you posted, verbatim, but couldn't reproduce. So the problem must be in the code you didn't post. https://gist.github.com/jnizet/5ce2971a94fb6f88a746607243613ca7

Comment: 1. Why are you using 3DES (DESede), that should not be used for new work, school project that requires 3DES? 2. A 3DES key is 24-bytes for the 168-bit key, "com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeKey@4f964d80" is not a 3DES key. While a 3DES key is 24-bytes, some implementations will accept a shorter key and replicate portions to create 24-byte key. 3. Why are you Base64 encoding the 3rd field, isn't it text? 4. There is no mention of padding, it is best to explicitly specify all parameters. 5. What is the value of: `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`?

Comment: 1. Ye, it’s a school project
2. That part was found somewhere in internet, because I had problem with figuring out how to provide the correct 3DES key. What should I use instead of this?
3. 1st, by encryption, I do convert the SecretKey to String, so I can display it in `textAreaKey`. Then, by decryption, I’m converting the text from `textAreaKey` back to SecretKey (added code in the question)
4. I don’t really know what do you mean here, I'm rather a beginner in this. 
5. When I tried now to `System.out.println("Value of Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE: " + Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);` it gives just `1`

Comment: `new String(encryptedBytes, "UTF8")`: that makes no sense. You can't just take arbitrary bytes and pretend ithey're a UTF8 encoded string. If you want the encryted bytes as printable text, do what you're already using for the key: encode it with base64. Note that you'd better use StandardCharsets.UTF_8, instead of "UTF8".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is here:

```
String encryptedText = new String(encryptedBytes, "UTF8");
```

Generally, many byte sequences in cipher text are not valid UTF-8–encoded characters. When you try to create a `String`, this malformed sequences will be replaced with the "replacement character", and then information from the the cipher text is irretrievably lost. When you convert the `String` back to bytes and try to decrypt it, the corrupt cipher text raises an error.

If you need to represent the cipher text as a character string, use base-64 encoding, just as you do for the key.

The other principal problem is that you are aren't specifying the full transformation. You should specify the "mode" and "padding" of the cipher explicitly, like "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding".

The correct mode will depend on your assignment. ECB is generally not secure, but more secure modes add a bit of complexity that may be outside the scope of your assignment. Study your instructions and clarify the requirements with your teacher if necessary.

Comment: So, I replaced it with `String encryptedText = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);`. But how about this "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding"? Should I replace every "DESede" with that? When I tried, I got `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding KeyGenerator not available`. He doesn't really care, I already got a mark for this assignment, but it was decrypting only if I didn't restart the app and I wanted to improve this for myself and to try to do that with JavaFX instead of swing

Comment: Hmm, now, when  I've set it to `DESede` in `generateKey()` and to `DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding` in `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` I do not get `NoSuchAlgorithmException`, encryption works, but I'm still getting error by decryption: `java.security.InvalidKeyException: Wrong algorithm: DESede or TripleDES required`

Comment: @zygmunt I'd have to see your current code. Are you still specifying "DESede" when creating your `SecretKeySpec` for decryption?

Comment: No, I changed it to `DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding`, I've updated the code in the question

Comment: @zygmunt "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding" should *only* appear in each occurrence of `Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`. Every `new SecretKeySpec()` should use just "DESede".

Comment: Ok, I've changed that. Now I'm getting `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:989)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:845)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESedeCipher.engineDoFinal(DESedeCipher.java:294)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
 at encryption_app.Encryption.decrypt(Encryption.java:46)` - that's the line with `byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes);` in decrypt() method

Comment: @zygmunt `byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptedText.getBytes("UTF8");` The cipher text is Base-64 encoded, not UTF-8, because that doesn't work for cipher text.

Comment: Oh, right, changed it to `byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(encryptedText.getBytes());`, but still have that BadPaddingException

Comment: @zygmunt decode the string. You just double-base-64 encoded it.

Comment: Damn me, right... Now it's decrypting without any error, but the decrypted text is not valid. Using this code I've got key by encryption looking like `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@4f965208` and by decryption `jjavax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@4f965208
`. I also tried to use gusto2 code, then both keys look like `javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@b069a0ca`, but decrypted text still looks like this: "CpoLw+MN4oJSotYflOSf0N3PO9hZ7HYtnYsTeEyAx/hq47ofrFk3UCMpSSs3Jo0F"

Comment: @zygmunt That's because you are base-64 encoding the plain text *before* encrypting. That's not necessary. Just do `byte[] plainTextByte = plainText.getBytes(); byte[] encryptedBytes = Encryption.encrypt(plainTextByte, klucz);`

Comment: Still getting the same results. decodedKey looks different each time I press "Decrypt" button

Comment: @zygmunt My guess is you have screwed up again and that you are encrypting the base-64-encoded key. Make sure that the input to the encryption function is coming from the plain text text-area.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question. The input to the encryption function is plainTextBytes and the key, the key is encoded to String later. By encrypting I'm converting the key to `byteKey`, then to `stringKey`, and by decrypting `stringKey` looks same, but when I convert it to byte[] `decodedKey` it's not equal to `byteKey`. Each time I click "decrypt', the `decodedKey` changes, but decryptedText stays same

Comment: @zygmunt you are base-64 encoding `decryptedBytes` at the end of your decryption action. You should just re-create the original string: `String decryptedText = new String(decryptedBytes)`

Comment: Finally! thank you for your help and most of all for your patience

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues:

1. You should not use user entered password as a key (there are difference between them). The key must have specific size depending on the cipher (16 or 24 bytes for 3des)
2. Direct 3DES (DESede) is a block cipher encrypting 8 bytes at once. To encrypt multiple blocks, there are some methods defined how to do that properly. It is calls [Block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

For proper encryption you need to take care of a few more things

**Creating a key from the password**

Let's assume you want to use DESede (3des). **The key must have fixed size - 16 or 24 bytes. To properly generate a key from password you should use [PBKDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)**. Some people are sensitive to "must use", however neglecting this step really compromises the encryption security mainly using user-entered passwords.

For 3DES you can use :

```
        int keySize = 16*8;
        int iterations = 800000;
        char[] password = "password".toCharArray();
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] salt = random.generateSeed(8);

        SecretKeyFactory secKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, keySize);
        SecretKey pbeSecretKey = secKeyFactory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey desSecret = new SecretKeySpec(pbeSecretKey.getEncoded(), "DESede");

        // iv needs to have block size
        // we will use the salt for simplification
        IvParameterSpec ivParam = new IvParameterSpec(salt);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESEde/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,  desSecret, ivParam);

        System.out.println("salt: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(salt));
        System.out.println(cipher.getIV().length+" iv: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.getIV()));
        byte[] ciphertext = cipher.doFinal("plaintext input".getBytes());
        System.out.println("encrypted: "+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ciphertext));
```

if you can ensure that your password has good entropy (is long and random enough) you may be good with a simple hash

```
        MessageDigest dgst = MessageDigest.getInstance("sha-1");
        byte[] hash = dgst.digest("some long, complex and random password".getBytes());
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize/8];
        System.arraycopy(hash, 0, keyBytes, 0, keySize/8);
        SecretKey desSecret = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
```

The **salt** serves to randomize the output and should be used.

The output of the encryption should be `salt | cipthertext | tag` (not necessarily in this order, but you will need all of these for proper encryption).

To decrypt the output, you will need to split the output to salt, ciphertext and the tag.

I see zero vectors ( static salt or iv ) very often in examples from StackOverflow, but in many cases it may lead to broken ciphers revelaling key or plaintext.

**The initialization vector** *iv*  is needed for block chain modes (encrypting longer input than a single block), we could use the salt from the key as well 
when having the same size ( 8 bytes in our case). For really secure solution the password salt should be longer.

The tag is an authentication tag, to ensure that nobody has manipulated with the ciphertext. You could use HMAC of the plaintext or ciphertext. It is important you should use different key for HMAC than for encryption. However - I believe in your case your homework will be ok even without the hmac tag

Comment: I will take a closer look at it tomorrow, but I'm afrait that it will be a little bit too complicated for me

Comment: @zygmunt crypto is hard to do properly. People are neglecting details and then it will result to broken implementations. When creating a security product, make sure you understand what are you doing :/

Comment: @zygmunt I've created (for other reasons) a [blog post](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) , you could check "password symmetric encryption" . There's how to create a encryption key from password